LaTeX file not running in texmaker on Fedora (but fine on MacOS): Error : could not start the command : biber
I have been using MacOS, but recently, I decided to jump from MacOS to Linux running Fedora 40. LaTeX is installed on Fedora and I use texmaker on both operating systems to edit documents.
Today, I tried to run the exact same file in texmaker on Fedora which I run before on MacOS. In contrast to before, it just won`t compile.
Please see the code here:
%% start of file `template.tex'.
%% Copyright 2006-2015 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c,
% available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=apa,
sorting=nty
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % needed for quick compiling using fn+F1

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'banking', 'oldstyle' and 'fancy'
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               % color options 'black', 'blue' (default), 'burgundy', 'green', 'grey', 'orange', 'purple' and 'red'
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

%\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans} % specifies font
\renewcommand\rmdefault{cmr}
\renewcommand\sfdefault{cmss}
\renewcommand\ttdefault{cmtt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % needed for character encryption, instead of \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} used

% character encoding
% usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.8, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % needed for page numbers
\usepackage{lastpage} % needed for page numbers

\usepackage{xcolor} % needed for additional colors

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[]{fontawesome5} % needed for adjusted symbols at phone number and email

\usepackage{stringstrings} 

\usepackage{ragged2e} % needed for justification of text (Blocksatz instead of raggedright or so)

%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DEFINE COLORS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\definecolor{white}{RGB}{255,255,255} % needed for \icon command
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{4D4D4D}
\definecolor{black}{HTML}{000000}
\definecolor{sidecolor}{HTML}{E7E7E7}
\definecolor{mainblue}{HTML}{0E5484} % needed for \icon command
\definecolor{maingray}{HTML}{B9B9B9}

\definecolor{frontColor}{rgb}{0.22,0.45,0.70}% light blue
\definecolor{backColor}{RGB}{200,200,200}% grey

\colorlet{color1}{mainblue} % assign mainblue to color 1 for the correct color of name in title

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ALIGN ADDRESS SYMBOL WITH PHONE SYMBOL %%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter

%   internal command to flush the makehead
\@initializecommand{\flushmakeheaddetails}{%
  \ifnum\makeheaddetailsboxwidth>0%
    \strut\usebox{\makeheaddetailsbox}%
    \savebox{\makeheaddetailsbox}{}%
    \savebox{\makeheaddetailstempbox}{}%
    \setlength{\makeheaddetailsboxwidth}{0pt}\fi}
\@initializecommand{\makehead}{%
  \setlength{\makeheaddetailswidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
  \hfil%
  \parbox{\makeheaddetailswidth}{%
    \centering%
    % name and title
    \vspace{-2cm} % CHANGED: adjust to specify height of name and contact details on page
    \namestyle{\@firstname~\@lastname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\titlestyle{~|~\@title}}% \isundefined doesn't work on \@title, as LaTeX itself defines \@title (before it possibly gets redefined by \title) 
    % optional detailed information
    \vspace{0.4cm} % CHANGED: adjust the vertical space between name and contact details
    \if@details{%
      \\%
%      \raggedright % CHANGED: left-align address block :: Uncomment for address first and aligned with phone symbol
%      \hspace{1.08cm} % CHANGED: adjust the horizontal space manually such that the address and phone symbol are aligned :: Uncomment for address first and aligned with phone symbol
%      \addressfont\color{color2}% :: Uncomment for address first and aligned with phone symbol
%      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\addresssymbol\href{https://osm.org/go/0JrItkpzc--?m=&way=383042322}{\@addressstreet}}% % CHANGED: insert link which points to address on a map! :: Uncomment for address first and aligned with phone symbol
%        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails[~--~]{\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and \addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty :: Uncomment for address first and aligned with phone symbol
%        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails[~--~]{\@addresscountry}}%  :: Uncomment for address first and aligned with phone symbol
%        \flushmakeheaddetails\@firstmakeheaddetailselementtrue\\}% :: Uncomment for address first and aligned with phone symbol
%      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@born}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\bornsymbol\@born}}% :: Uncomment for address first and aligned with phone symbol
%      \vspace{0.2cm} %CHANGED: introduce some vertical space between address and rest of additional information :: Uncomment for address first and aligned with phone symbol
      \centering % CHANGED: center the rest of the additional information
      \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\addresssymbol\href{https://osm.org/go/0JrDODV-?relation=109166}{\@addressstreet}}} % delete this (the address) ifthenelse for having the address above phone and email and aligned with phone symbol
        \addtomakeheaddetails{\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\homepagesymbol\httpslink{\@homepage}}}%
      \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
        \addtomakeheaddetails{\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\addtomakeheaddetails{\@extrainfo}}%
      \flushmakeheaddetails}\fi}\\[2.5em]}% need to force a \par after this to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makehead
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%% ADJUSTMENT OF ICONS FOR PHONE AND EMAIL %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% IMPORTANT NOTE: originally, the fontawesome5 package is loaded without the parameter "fixed". To get same size icons I added the parameter. In more detail, the file can be found here /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncviconsawesome.sty and "[fixed]" was added where the package is loaded. 

\patchcmd{\makeheaddetailssymbol} % deletes the dot between phone and email but keeps the spacing
  {\textbullet}% to search
  {}%            replacement
  {}{}%          success failure

\newcommand*\icon[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt, fill=mainblue,mainblue,text=white] (char) {#1};}} % command needed to create blue circle with following phone and email symbols in it

\renewcommand*{\mobilephonesymbol} {{\textsc{\icon{\faPhone}}}~} % change standard phone symbol to current blue and white one
\renewcommand*{\emailsymbol}         {{\textsc{\icon{\faAt}}}~} % change standard email symbol to current blue and white one
%\newcommand{\addresssymbol}{\icon{\faMapMarker}~}
\renewcommand*{\addresssymbol}         {{\textsc{\icon{\faMapMarker}}}~} % change standard address symbol to current blue and white one


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% CHANGE FONT OF TITLE OR NAME %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% IMPORTANT NOTE: Other style changes of the header can be done in two ways. 1) go to file /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/moderncvheadiii.sty (REMEMBER: Banking = iii) and edit directly this file. 2) Copy the respective command into this file and \renewcommand{•}{•} here.

\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{25}{40}\bfseries\upshape} % set the name font equal to title font
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\fontsize{25}{40}\bfseries\upshape} % to change the title font

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% CHANGE NAME AND CLOSING NAME %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\firstcap}[1]{\caselower[e]{#1}\capitalize{\thestring}} % new command to convert a capital lastname such as ZEROBIN to Zerobin for the name in the signature

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makeletterclosing}{
  \@closing\\[1em] % 1em is spacing below 'closing{}' command
  {\@firstname~\firstcap{\@lastname}}
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@enclosure}}{}{%
    \\%
    \vspace{1cm} % spacing between signature and 'enclosure{}'
    {\color{color2}\itshape\enclname: \@enclosure}}}
\makeatother


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ADJUST RECIPIENT NAME ADDRESS STRUCTURE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makeletterhead}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputeletterlengths%
  % sender block
  \makehead%
  \par%
  \vspace{-0.2cm} % CHANGE THIS VALUE TO ADJUST VSPACE BETWEEN PERSONAL INFORMATION AND RECIPIENT INFORMATION
   % recipient block
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.8\textwidth}
    \raggedright%
    \addressfont%
    {\bfseries\upshape\@recipientname}\\%
    \@recipientaddress%
  \end{minipage}
  % date
  \hfill% US style
%  \\[1em]% UK style
  \@date\\[2em]% US informal style: "January 1, 1900"; UK formal style: "01/01/1900"
  % opening
  \raggedright
  \@opening\\[1.5em]%
  % ensure no extra spacing after \makelettertitle due to a possible blank line
%  \ignorespacesafterend% not working
  \hspace{0pt}\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}}

\makeatother


%%%%%%%%%%%%% PAGE NUMBERING %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagestyle{fancy} % set page style
\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage{} of \pageref{LastPage}} % define page numbering in right footer


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% PERSONAL INFORMATION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% CHANGE LINE 81 TO ALIGN ADDRESS AND PHONE SYMBOL MANUALLY

\name{FirstNAME}{LastNAME}
\title{Cover Letter} % \vspace{} introduced for some spacing between title and address block
\address{XYXYXYXY}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
% See above to insert link which points to address on a map!
\phone[mobile]{+00 1234 56789}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the optional "type" of the phone can be "mobile" (default), "fixed" or "fax"
%\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
%\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{first.last@email.com}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\social[linkedin]{john.doe}                        % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\social[twitter]{jdoe}                             % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\social[github]{jdoe}                              % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                       % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file
%\quote{Some quote}                                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

% bibliography adjustements (only useful if you make citations in your resume, or print a list of publications using BibTeX)
%   to show numerical labels in the bibliography (default is to show no labels)
%\makeatletter\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}\makeatother
%   to redefine the bibliography heading string ("Publications")
%\renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}

% bibliography with mutiple entries
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\hypersetup{allbordercolors=red, pdfborder = 0 0 1}

%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient{Recepient Name}{
Street and Number, \\
District City, \\
Country}
\date{\today}
\opening{%\textbf{Application for the vacant Pre-Doc position} \\ [0.6cm]
To whom it may concern, \vspace{-0.4cm}}
\closing{Sincerely,}
%\enclosure[Attached]{CV}   % use an optional argument to use a string other than "Enclosure", or redefine \enclname
\makelettertitle
\justify % justify (Blocksatz) text instead of raggedright

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Intro %%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\lipsum[1-2]

\makeletterclosing % automatically inserts the 'closing{}', 'name{}{}' and 'enclosure{}' at the end of the letter including some spacing

\end{document}


%% end of file `template.tex'.

Whenever I press F1 in order to quick compile it, the output is: Error : could not start the command : biber "test" where "test" is the filename.
Of course, I verfified whether biber % is written in Bib(la)tex setting.
I just tried again to compile it on my MacOS machine and it runs without any problems. So, any help would be greatly appreciated as I do not know how to proceed.
EDIT: running biber --version returns version 2.19 and to be sure I ran sudo dnf install texlive-scheme-full which resulted in the message that the package is already installed

Hello! Does biber work on command line? It could be that your Fedora install might be missing some library dependencies for biber.

Could you tell ma a quick command to check whether it works in command line?

Just open a terminal and run biber with no parameters, it should give us some hints.

The output of biber is: `Usage:
biber [options] file[.bcf]
biber [options] --tool 
  Creates "file.bbl" using control file "file.bcf" (".bcf" extension is
  optional). Normally use with biblatex requires no options as they are
  all set in biblatex and passed via the ".bcf" file

  In "tool" mode (see B<--tool> option), takes a datasource (defaults to
  "bibtex" datasource) and outputs a copy of the datasource with any command-line
  or config file options applied.

  Please run "biber --help" for option details`


Thanks, so it's not a library problem! biber should be working on your system.

Can you try with the full path to biber in your texmaker preferences?

Exactly which latex have you installed on your fedora? My guess: you have two latex installations, the correct one only works in a terminal. The other is used in your editor and does not include biber. Try starting your editor from he terminal and see if that makes a difference

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz could you let me know how to 1) figure out the full path to biber on Fedora and 2) how to specify it in texmaker correctly?

@daleif unfortunately, I do not know how to figure that out correctly. I would argue that I only have one installation on my machine, but I do not know how to confirm that.

@m0byn Use which biber on the command line to see the path. Then go to your texmaker preferences and replace biber %  with /whateever/your/full/path/is/biber %

But how exactly did you install LaTeX in your Fedora? Using the package manager or installing manually from tug.org/texlive. It is your PC, only you know what you did. If you installed TeXLive manually from tug.org/texlive, then it is very easy to install LaTeX from Fedora as well (a minimal version), because of recommneds for your editor. Then if you did not correctly add the PATH of your manual TeXLive to your setup, you can end in a situation like this.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I replaced biber % with /bin/biber % where biber is installed in bin`. However, unfortunately nothing changed. Still the same problem as before.

@m0byn Don't forget the %: /bin/biber %

@daleif I used sudo dnf install texlive-scheme-full. However, Fedora comes with LaTeX preinstalled, so the command I used returned package is already installed. Can you help me out?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz yeah sorry, I had it added. Going to edit my previous comment now.

Finally, I found the solution to fix the issue. For a more detailed discussion read this post. Summing up, I apparently was running the flatpak version instead of the rpm version. After uninstalling the flatpak version, then installing the rpm version, everything works as expected.
